# Visual Studio Intellisense suggestion arrows shortcut

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to find a keyboard shortcuts to navigate thru IntelliSense suggestion arrows (marked area on the pic).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the up/down and left/right arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

I have got somewhere a tip (and tested it) to hit escape key, which closes the bottom right box and then arrows will navigate the left box.